# Running Spark job in dataproc with docker-compose

Tags: docker, apache-spark, docker-compose, google-cloud-dataproc

I have created and tested successfully a project which runs locally with docker-compose using sample data. Bash file to run the whole pipeline job:

```
cp -r ../data . # transfer data used for job

docker-compose up --build -d
docker exec project_master_1 bin/spark-submit \
                            --py-files /project/utils.py\
                            /project/main.py
docker cp project_master_1:/project/data/output/. ../project/output #some tranfer of generated files
docker exec project_master_1 rm -rf /project/data

docker-compose down
```

My docker-compose file is identical to the one from this: [github link](https://github.com/gettyimages/docker-spark/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)

So what I do is to create a dataproc cluster with initialization action to install docker:

```
gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/docker/docker.sh
```

Next:

- I enter with ssh the master
- git clone my project(this can be done also in initialization action(???))
- install docker-compose
- run the bash file.

It starts running but it seems that it runs only in master and not in the workers. So what do I do wrong here? Any insight is useful.

Answer (score 0):

By default, spark-submit doesn't execute programs in YARN. You should specify parameter [`--master yarn`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls) so that the job can be executed in the workers. Something like this should start the job in the cluster:

```
docker exec project_master_1 bin/spark-submit \
    --master yarn \
    --py-files /project/utils.py \
    /project/main.py
```

For spark-submit to be able to find the YARN cluster, you have to set HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR variable to point to the configuration files of the cluster, especially yarn-site.xml.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to perform an action on all nodes (masters and workers), you should consider modifying your initialization-action (start with a copy of docker.sh) to do so. "git clone" does work in the initialization action script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not useful at all.

Comment: Please include information on how to modify initialization script.